# Is there any NodeJS bcrypt module that does not rely on node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I was wondering if there's a chance to distribute software that uses bcrypt without having to depend on the user having node-gyp installed.

The [bcrypt npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) does depend on the user having node-gyp installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) is a pure-javascript implementation and available in npm.

Comment: Went with this one. A realiable alternative!

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275187/are-there-any-slow-javascript-hashing-algorithms-like-bcrypt) has a good overview of the options available.

Based on that, and a cursory googling, [javascript-bcrypt](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/) may be your best bet. It's not a Node module, but including it is super simple.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that question